# How do you unit test ngrx effects with Angular 6 and without jasmine-marbles?

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular6, ngrx-effects, rxjs6

I am trying to write some unit tests for my effects, but it seems like the test does not reach the part where I have my `expect`.  I don't want to use `jasmine-marbles`, I just want to use plain `jasmine` out of the box.

**Effects**

```
@Effect
loadData$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.LOAD_DATA),
    switchMap(actions =>
        this.dataService.getData().pipe(
            map(data => new actions.LoadDataSuccess(data)),
            catchError(err => of(new actions.LoadDataFailed(err)))
        )
    )
);
```

**spec file**

```
let effects: fromData.DataEffects;
let actions: Observable<any>;
let mockState: fromData.DataState;
let mockDataService: jasmine.SpyObj<DataService>;

beforeEach((async(() => {
    mockState = { name: 'Test', age: 40 };
    mockDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj({'dataService', getData: of<Data>(mockState)});
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        providers: [
            fromData.DataEffects,
            provideMockActions(() => actions),
            { provide: DataService, useValue: mockDataService }
        ]
    });
    effects = TestBed.get(fromData.DataEffects);
})));

it('should return new success action after load', fakeAsync(() => {
    let data: any;
    const actions = new ReplaySubject(1);
    actions.next(new fromData.LoadAction());
    effects.loadData$.subscribe(result => {
        data = result;
    });
    tick(100);
    expect(data).toEqual(fromData.LoadDataSuccess);
}));
```

The test is failing because `Expected undefined to equal Function`.

Note I am using **Angular 6** with the latest `ngrx` and **RxJS 6**.

Thanks!

Comment: try to change time inside tick, give it more and try again

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
effects.loadData$.subscribe(result => {
    data = result;
    expect(data).toEqual(fromData.LoadDataSuccess);
});
```

Comment: this code does make the test pass, but I threw in some garbage data in the `toEqual()` function and it still passed the test.  I think the problem is that the code inside the `subscribe` never fires, or there is something wrong with the setup of my effects.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, had to use a `ReplaySubject` from rxjs.  Had to instantiate a new `ReplaySubject` as my `actions` object in the `beforeEach(async(())` function.

```
actions = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

Then in my unit test:

```
it('should return new success action after load', (done) => {
    actions.next(new fromData.LoadAction());
    const sub = effects.loadData$.subscribe(result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(fromData.LoadDataSuccess(mockState));
        done();
        setTimeout(() => sub.unsubscribe());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock Actions from '@ngrx/effects' with Subject from 'rxjs'

```
const actions = new Subject();
```

and then in providers of testing module

```
{ provide: Actions, useValue: actions }
```

in your unit test when you need trigger some effect subscribe to your effect to test your expected action/behaviour. Then simple call actions.next(new TriggerAction()).